# CMake file for integrated Visual Studio unit testing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, cmake

Visual Studio 2017 has integrated C++ unit testing (native, google test, ctest, etc.). How can I create a CMakeLists.txt file that will create a project like this that will use the integrated IDE testing, for example using either google test or the native microsoft unit testing framework? All of Microsoft's examples unfortunately just create the project in Visual Studio, rather than starting from a CMake file.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mikewho,

I setup a small example using Google Test project that works with integrated IDE testing.

Create an empty directory and save these two files:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test_me)

# GTest
enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Unit Tests
# Add test cpp file
add_executable( runUnitTests tests.cpp)
# Link test executable against gtest & gtest_main
target_link_libraries(runUnitTests ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES})
add_test( runUnitTests runUnitTests )
```

tests.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(ABC, TEST1) {
  EXPECT_EQ(true, true);
}
```

The in a command prompt type

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

Note: I had vcpkg install gtest

```
C:\dev\vcpkg>vcpkg.exe install gtest
```

Make sure you have this installed in Visual Studio 2017
[image]

In Tools > Options > Test Adapter for Google Test set the regex to .exe
[image]

Build the solution and press Run all in the Test Explorer
[image]

The first time it runs it will find the test case

```
[12/3/2018 8:38:41 AM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[12/3/2018 8:38:42 AM Warning] Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\dev\cpptests\GoogleTest\build\Debug\runUnitTests.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '<ForceListContent>' via a .runsettings file.
[12/3/2018 8:38:42 AM Informational] Test Adapter for Google Test: Test execution starting...
**[12/3/2018 8:38:42 AM Informational] Found 1 tests in executable** C:\dev\cpptests\GoogleTest\build\Debug\runUnitTests.exe
[12/3/2018 8:38:42 AM Informational] Running 1 tests...
[12/3/2018 8:38:42 AM Informational] Google Test execution completed, overall duration: 00:00:00.2390446
[12/3/2018 8:38:42 AM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:01.2668844) ==========
```

I hope this helps?

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. I've marked it as the answer. If you happen to have time it would be great to know how to tweak this for the microsoft unit testing framework?

Comment: Please open another question with MS unit testing framework and I will answer it.

Comment: I've posted it, thanks!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709197/cmake-for-integrated-microsoft-unit-testing-framework-vs2017

Comment: At first, I couldn't figure out why it doesn't work for me. The VS and cmake still couldn't find gtest package. Then I figured it out. I had to explicitly install x64 package. 
.\vcpkg install gtest:x64-windows

Comment: Another thing, if after installing the package you do: ".\vcpkg.exe integrate install" it will hook up all the packages installed into VS and then you won't need to run cmake with CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE specified for VS to see the packages.

Comment: Why does the test result not appear in Test Explorer when I add the gtest header file installed by vcpkg to the *.sln project?

Answer (score 2):

Although this is a late reply, but it's the latest answer for any reference.

For **Microsoft Unit Testing Framework**, the following *simplified files* work with me:

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(UNIT_TEST_TARGET_NAME my_lib)
add_library(${UNIT_TEST_TARGET_NAME} SHARED)
target_sources(${UNIT_TEST_TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE 
    tests.cpp
    tests.h
)
target_link_libraries(${UNIT_TEST_TARGET_NAME} 
    PRIVATE MSUnitTestFramework::MSUnitTestFramework)
enable_testing()
find_program(VSTest_EXECUTABLE NAME vstest.console.exe REQUIRED)
list(PREPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(MSUnitTestFramework REQUIRED)
add_test(NAME ${UNIT_TEST_TARGET_NAME} 
    COMMAND "${VSTest_EXECUTABLE}" "${CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${UNIT_TEST_TARGET_NAME}.dll"
)
```

`/cmake/FindMSUnitTestFramework.cmake`

```
add_library(MSUnitTestFramework::MSUnitTestFramework SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(MSUnitTestFramework::MSUnitTestFramework PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "$ENV{VCInstallDir}Auxiliary/VS/UnitTest/include"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "$ENV{VCInstallDir}Auxiliary/VS/UnitTest/lib/x86/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib"
)
set(MSUnitTestFramework_FOUND TRUE)
```

`tests.cpp`

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
namespace my_unit_test
{
    TEST_CLASS(my_tests)
    {
    public:
        TEST_METHOD(test1)
.
.
```

You can `Run All Tests` and so on from MSVC.

BTW, instead of `add_test` for the whole DLL, you can use it to add test by test.