# Visual Studio Test Explorer - GTest with CMake and remote build

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019, googletest

I have a C++ linux project, developed on Windows with VS2019 and deployed to a remote build machine.

I am trying to set up unit testing with googletest.

I have created an example project using CMake and am able to get my tests to run on the remote build machine, but I would like for them to appear in the VS Test Explorer.

I have tried the suggetions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583286), but I think they are for Windows deployment and they did not work for me.

Is it possible to discover tests from a project deployed to linux and if so, how?

My project directory is set up like this:

```
ExampleProject
|  CMakeLists.txt
|  CMakeLists.txt.in
|  main.cpp
|__src
   |  CMakeLists.txt
   |  example.cpp
   |  example.h
|__test
   |  CMakeLists.txt
   |  example_add.cpp
```

The outer CMakeLists.txt is set up like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# set the project name
project(ExampleProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
    RESULT_VARIABLE result
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if (result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
    RESULT_VARIABLE result
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if (result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Add googletest directly to our build. This defines
# the gtest and gtest_main targets.
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# The gtest/gtest_main targets carry header search path
# dependencies automatically when using CMake 2.8.11 or
# later. Otherwise we have to add them here ourselves.
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
    include_directories("${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()

add_subdirectory(src)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(tests)

# add the executable
add_executable(ExampleProject main.cpp)
```

CMakeLists.txt.in is copied from googletest:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)

project(googletest-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
    GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
    GIT_TAG           master
    SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
    BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND     ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
    TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

The CMakeLists.txt for src is:

```
add_library(example example.cpp)
target_include_directories(example PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

And the CMakeLists.txt for test is:

```
add_executable(ExampleTest example_add.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ExampleTest gtest gtest_main example)
add_test(ExampleTest ExampleTest)
```

Comment: I think the test explorer is a bit buggy. Have also worked with the test explorer and trying to get it to manage test cases. It looks like it needs some more work to do it's job.
What worked for me was to create "add_test" runs in CMakeLists.txt files. Also remember to add `enable_testing` in the CMakeLists.txt root folder. Test to put that command early. I think VC scans the file and tries to figure out what is configured.

Comment: Add `include(CTest)` in your top CMakeLists.txt (https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/26109#issuecomment-1201955215)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Danae Xiao [MSFT]

> the [CMAKE] tests are not supported in Test Explorer under WSL/Linux configurations.

Please refer to this discussion at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/955742/googletest-cmake-project-wsl.html

Comment: Are they supported for native (local non-WSL builds)?

Comment: Hey, @jacobq! If I understand you correctly, CMAKE tests are supported in Test Explorer under Windows. On my last project that used WSL I was building and unit testing with GTest the same codebase for local Windows and WSL Linux. And under Windows the Test Explorer mainly worked out of the box.